# Babel transform, get value of parent scope constant

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, babeljs

Assume I have such Javascript code

```
import someFunc from 'somewhere';
const prefix = 'Planet';
someFunc(prefix + 'Earth');
```

If I use babeljs in my project I can write simple transform plugin

```
export default function({types: t}) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      CallExpression: {
        enter(path, {opts, file}) {
          if (path.node.callee.name !== 'someFunc') {
            return;
          }
          <...>
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I take 'prefix' variable value inside plugin or evaluate whole BinaryExpression expression to replace it with result string to get this?

```
import someFunc from 'somewhere';
someFunc('PlanetEarth');
```

Comment: What is `someFunc`? Is it equal to your export function?

Comment: No, it's some imported function

Comment: I think you're confusing _translation time_ with _runtime_. While `Babel` is performing the transformation, the variable `prefix` doesn't exist. The code isn't actually _running_. You can access the syntatic token found in the code, but not its value.

Comment: @slezica Yeah, I want to replace in "transformation time" :)
To stay on safe side, I use 'const'

Comment: And I can reach prefix value like this, but it seems like too 'glibly'
path.scope.bindings.prefix.path.get('value').parent.init.value

Comment: It's not a very solid approach. You can get at that value pretty incidentally, it will not be the case in any syntax except static initialization with a primitive value. What you're doing looks interesting, but I think it's not a good idea :( it won't hold under non-ideal conditions

Comment: [`callee` is forbidden in "strict mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) and [ES6 modules are automatically strict-mode](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)

Comment: @slezica Well, many optimizing compilers do exactly this kind of thing. Under what non-ideal conditions would it not hold up?

Comment: @laggingreflex Thank you, co)) But here is AST node property, not arguments.callee property